# TO_CHAR only considering dates while comparing two time stamps?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below query condition is failing but logically it should pass. Is something wrong with to_char??

```
SELECT data
FROM table1
WHERE
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(value1, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') <= 
   TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
 AND TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(value2, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') >=
    TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS');

value1='02/07/2014 12:30:10'
value2='06/08/2015 09:57:33'
```

in both the conditions it is only checking the dates i.e.,02<=07 (7th is todays date).First condition is getting satisfied regardless of month and year.if i change value1 to `'15/08/2014 12:30:10'`  it is failing. Same with second condition.

Comment: Why are you storing dates as varchar?

Comment: That is user input so i have to store it in varchar which is done from a d2k application on which i don't want to make any change. So i have to store it in varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after lot of googling i got the solution. Below query is working for me :) :)

SELECT MESSAGE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(value1, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') <= CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP)
AND TO_TIMESTAMP(value2, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') >= CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP);

value1='02/07/2014 12:30:10'
value2='06/08/2015 09:57:33'

Answer (score 4):

Why are you comparing dates as strings?  This also begs the question of why you would store dates as strings in the first place.  You should store date/times using the built-in types.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT data
FROM table1
WHERE TO_DATE(value1, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') <= sysdate AND
      TO_DATE(value2, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') >= sysdate;
```

Your problem is presumably that you are comparing strings, rather than dates.  And the format you are using `DD/MM/YYYY` doesn't do comparisons the same way.  This is, in fact, why you should just use the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD whenever you are storing date/time values in strings (which I don't recommend in most cases anyway).

If your values are already stored in proper types, then you can just do:

```
SELECT data
FROM table1
WHERE value1 <= sysdate AND
      value2 >= sysdate;
```

If these are timestamps with time zone, then you can use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead of `SYSDATE`.

Comment: I agree. If you plan to use the data as a timestamp than better store it as a timestamp. This also gives the possibility to easily add indexes if necessary.

Comment: Thanks gordan. value1 ,value2 are changable. i mean user wants to display a message on screen between those time stamps.I need time stamp not only a simple date. So user changes it frequently. Also this entry is done from a d2k form. it is something i want to make it work by changing in the query itself. Is there any other way??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TO_TIMESTAMP instead of TO_DATE:

```
SELECT data
FROM table1
WHERE  
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(value1, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') <= 
   TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
  AND TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(value2, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS') >=
    TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense - If you use TO_CHAR you will compare TEXT and sorting it by alphabet, this only works with ISO-Standard formats. And is not even needed, since Oracle can natively compare Dates!